# How do I replace a file on firebase storage bucket?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am uploading images to my firebase storage bucket from a node.js server as follows:

```
bucket.upload(files.image.path, {metadata: {contentType: files.image.type}});
```

A also want to replace files that have already been upload. For example, if I edit the file and I want to upload the new version, overwriting the old version.

I read on google that I can replace files by specifying the name of the old file, but I tried the following which didn't seem to work:

```
bucket.upload(files.image.path, {metadata: {contentType: files.image.type, name: fields.filename}});
```

...but it told me:

```
Value 'upload_8b8702384ca2686b8a0a0de7102f2804' in content does not agree with value 'upload_73065f47da4149eee391cd09a01f628a'. This can happen when a value set through a parameter is inconsistent with a value set in the request.
```

What would be the right way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: I'm unclear what you're trying to achieve.  Please edit the question to say more about what you mean by "replace files that have already been upload".  Uploading a file with the same name should overwrite the old file.

Comment: If you could please, clarify your question, adding what specifically you want to achieve and what it's happening now, it will be easier for the Community to understand.

Comment: Hi both, I added more detail as requested. Hopefully it's more clear now. Doug, you got it right, but I must have the syntax wrong in my example above. How do I specify the file name when I upload?

Comment: Ah, very insightful. Thanks everyone!